# Comparison of two datasets with different variables

Tags: anova, p-value, permutation-test

I am going to explain my problem as simple as I can. I have two sequences of DNA (two different datasets). Each sequence has three different variables or factors (for biologists: Hi-C, Chip-seq and methylation data). Each variable can be in the sequence or dataset many times (they can be summarized as counts).

My aim is to compare if both regions are statistically different or not.

Each variable, independently, can be analyzed using a simple permutation test but having three p-values. However, I do not know which test to use to consider all three variables at the same time to get a unique p-value.